# Custom ng-model Directive not firing digest

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive I have created to allow date input in a variety of formats, but when ever you finish entering a date and leave the input no digest is fired.

How can I get the digest to fire?

**Details**

The directive happily allows the user to enter text and to return a string in a standard date format for the model to consume if its a valid date.

It uses formatters and parsers to be able to do this and the actually processing is done in the on blur event for the input tag.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LLj8rW7uqNNdyYDy2VyS) shows the directive in action formatting a date and if you then alter the date in the input box you'll see that the bound value next to it never updates.

At this point all I need is for it to fire the digest/update the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add an `$apply` during the `bind`.  Whenever you are binding to DOM events, it is necessary to `$apply` to force a digest.

```
// configure events on the element
    function configureEvents(element, scope, ctrl, allowNull) {

        // remove handlers that would fire events while the user
        // is inputting data
        element.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');

        // bind to the blur event as we know the user should have 
        // finished inputting when they leave the control
        element.bind('blur',function() {

            scope.$apply(function() {
              processUserInput(element, ctrl, allowNull);
            });
        });
    }
```

In order to achieve this, I passed the scope to the `configureEvents`:

```
configureEvents(element, scope, ctrl, allowNull);
```

Here is a [fork of your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rxCeJjcVYg37Rsbq0Y3u?p=preview) that is working.